# Show something at a specific time each week using PHP

Tags: php

Using PHP, I have a DIV I need to show each week on Thursday from 7pm to 8pm (server time, not user time).  I'm thinking I need something with mktime here but I'm not sure how to make sure it does it each week at the same day/time interval.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( date('l') == "Thursday" && date('G') == 19 )
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the date function with the correct parameters to check the time frame you want.
For example:

```
if(date('N')==4)...   // Thursday

if(date('G')==19)...  // its 7.?? PM
```

etc.

or the fancy:

```
if(date('NG')=='419'){...}
```

Comment: `date('N')` 4 would be Friday wouldn't it? EDIT: Dahh, nope, it wouldn't. Ignore me.

Comment: Ok everyone, FROM THE MANUAL, 'N' is the 'ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week'. So 1=Mon, 2=Tues, 3=Wed AND 4=THURDAY.

Comment: Sorry... upvoting your answer now.

Comment: @Mischa No worries, its easy to get scrambled. You nearly scrambled me but all good in the end.

Comment: @zaf: "Everyone"? Only Nick got it wrong, and he very promptly corrected himself. So why are you shouting?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well there was a flurry of comments which were removed once I wrote my loud comment, and on top of that my answer had been edited with the wrong values - check it yourself. Sorry for shouting :)

Comment: @zaf: According to the edit history, _you're_ the one who edited it to 5 first :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, because of the comments I nearly got persuaded and the edits happened near enough at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (date("D") == "Thu" && date("H") == 19) {
   echo $yourDiv;
}
```

<sup>Next time please show us what you tried, then ask a question about a programming language! This isn't http://make-it-for-me.com</sup>

Comment: I looked around at several options and could not find anything that did this.  I experimented with mktime but didn't think of the more obvious of using just date.

Answer (score 2):

A simple if statement:

```
<?php
if (date('w')==4 && date('G') == 19) {
 // do stuff here
}
```

This would activate on Thursday at 19:00 and deactivate as soon as it hits 20:00