# Need specific time each week in PHP

Tags: php

I have a DIV on a page that I wanted to show only on Thursdays between 7pm and 8pm (local time) on a site.  I made a post a while back and found my answer for that. [Previous Post Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230462/show-something-at-a-specific-time-each-week-using-php)

I was using this code to do so:

```
if( date('l') == "Thursday" && date('G') >= 19 && date('G') < 20 )
```

However now I need to show the div from 6:59:30 to 8:01pm (server time) and I'm not quite sure how I would format the statement above for that?

This would need to run weekly for an indefinite time until I remove the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( date('l') == "Thursday" && date('Gis') >= 185930 && date('Gis') < 200100) {...
```

You should check out the php date manual for clarification: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I went and looked at PHP date and I think I like your answer for its brevity.  As usual, I was trying to make this much harder by thinking I would have to do something with the time() function and a lot of math.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (date('l') == 'Thursday' && time() >= strtotime('18:59:30')
   && time() <= strtotime('20:01:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (date('l') == "Thursday" && date('His') >= '185930' && date('His') <= '200100')
```

Comment: Sorry, complete brain fart (considering I use `H:i:s` about 10 times a week I should know). I meant that G has no leading zeros... not that it actually makes any difference. My original answer actually used `H` and I dropped it in favor of `G` for legibility.